# Imaginary part of expression too difficult to calculate

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, complex

I am trying to calculate the imaginary part of a long expression. It's a long enough expression that Mathematica "hangs" when you run:

```
imFUN2 = ComplexExpand[Im[expression]];
```

Is there something I can do that can help speed things up?

Here is my full code:

```
expression = -((I Ωc (4 γa^4 + 16 Δd^4 - 48 Δd^3 Δp + 48 Δd^2 Δp^2 - 16 Δd Δp^3 + 4 I γa^3 
  (3 Δc + 6 Δd - 4 Δp - Δs) - 16 Δd^3 Δs + 32 Δd^2 Δp Δs - 16 Δd Δp^2 Δs - 4 Δd^2 Ωc^2 + 
  4 Δd Δp Ωc^2 + 4 Δd Δs Ωc^2 - 4 I dephasing Δd Ωd^2 + 12 Δd^2 Ωd^2 + 
  4 I dephasing Δp Ωd^2 - 24 Δd Δp Ωd^2 + 12 Δp^2 Ωd^2 - 8 Δd Δs Ωd^2 + 
  8 Δp Δs Ωd^2 - Ωc^2 Ωd^2 + Ωd^4 + 4 Δc^2 (4 Δd^2 - 4 Δd Δp + Ωd^2) - 
  2 γa^2 (4 Δc^2 + 26 Δd^2 + 10 Δp^2 + 2 Δc (13 Δd - 7 Δp - 2 Δs) + 
  6 Δp Δs - 2 Δd (18 Δp + 5 Δs) - Ωc^2 + 4 Ωd^2) + 4 Δc (8 Δd^3 - 4 Δd^2 (4 Δp + Δs) - 
  (4 Δp + Δs) Ωd^2 + Δd (8 Δp^2 + 4 Δp Δs - Ωc^2 + 4 Ωd^2)) - 2 I γa (24 Δd^3 + 
  4 Δc^2 (3 Δd - Δp) - 4 Δp^3 - 4 Δp^2 Δs - 4 Δd^2 (13 Δp + 4 Δs) + Δp Ωc^2 + Δs Ωc^2 - 
  2 I dephasing Ωd^2 - 10 Δp Ωd^2 - 3 Δs Ωd^2 + Δc (36 Δd^2 + 8 Δp^2 + 4 Δp Δs - 
  4 Δd (11 Δp + 3 Δs) - Ωc^2 + 7 Ωd^2) + Δd (32 Δp^2 + 20 Δp Δs - 3 Ωc^2 + 10 Ωd^2))))/
  ((γa + 2 I Δd) (2 γa^2 - 4 Δc^2 + 4 Δd Δp - 4 Δp^2 + 4 Δd Δs - 8 Δp Δs - 4 Δs^2 + 
  2 I γa (3 Δc + Δd - 3 (Δp + Δs)) + Δc (-4 Δd + 8 (Δp + Δs)) + Ωd^2) (4 I γa^3 (Δc - Δp) - 
  16 Δc^2 Δd Δp - 16 Δc Δd^2 Δp + 16 Δc^2 Δp^2 + 48 Δc Δd Δp^2 + 16 Δd^2 Δp^2 - 32 Δc Δp^3 -
  32 Δd Δp^3 + 16 Δp^4 - 4 Δc Δd Ωc^2 - 4 Δd^2 Ωc^2 + 8 Δc Δp Ωc^2 + 8 Δd Δp Ωc^2 - 
  8 Δp^2 Ωc^2 + Ωc^4 - 4 Δc^2 Ωd^2 - 4 Δc Δd Ωd^2 + 8 Δc Δp Ωd^2 + 8 Δd Δp Ωd^2 - 
  8 Δp^2 Ωd^2 - 2 Ωc^2 Ωd^2 + Ωd^4 + 2 γa^2 (-4 Δc^2 - 6 Δc Δd + 14 Δc Δp + 6 Δd Δp - 
  10 Δp^2 + Ωc^2 + Ωd^2) - 2 I γa (4 Δc^2 (Δd - 3 Δp) - 4 Δd^2 Δp + Δd (20 Δp^2 - 
  3 Ωc^2 - Ωd^2) + Δc (4 Δd^2 - 24 Δd Δp + 28 Δp^2 - 3 Ωc^2 - Ωd^2) + 4 Δp (-4 Δp^2 + 
  Ωc^2 + Ωd^2)) + 2 dephasing (2 γa^3 + 2 I γa^2 (2 Δc + 3 Δd - 5 Δp) + γa (-4 Δd^2 - 
  4 Δc (Δd - 3 Δp) + 20 Δd Δp - 16 Δp^2 + Ωc^2 + Ωd^2) + 2 I (4 Δd^2 Δp - 8 Δd Δp^2 +
  4 Δp^3 - Δp Ωc^2 + Δd Ωd^2 - Δp Ωd^2 + Δc (4 Δd Δp - 4 Δp^2 + Ωd^2)))))) /.
      {γa -> 1, dephasing -> 10^-4};

imFUN2 = ComplexExpand[Im[expression]];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not an elegant solution but it works

```
num = Numerator[expression];
den = Denominator[expression];
{reNum, imNum} = ComplexExpand[ReIm[num]];
{reDen, imDen} = ComplexExpand[ReIm[den]];
(imNum reDen - reNum imDen)/(reDen^2 + imDen^2)
```

I think the problem is the denominator which is huge but I am surprised that my approach is not included in `ComplexExpand`

Comment: This works for me, thanks. It is interesting though that you call ComplexExpand[ReIm[num]] inside your function. I guess I should always make sure I don't have fractions-inside-fractions before calling this. 

Also for completion it might be helpful for others to know that the real part is:
(reNum reDen + imNum imDen)/(reDen^2 + imDen^2)